# How does `select` handle multiple events at the same time?

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, select, tcp

I am trying to understand the following [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/). If I have 50 connections to this server and I send data through one of these sockets, the `select` block with the inner loop will capture what I send and echo it back. But what happens if within a very short time-frame of the first message, I send another one? So fast that the inner loop (after `select` - the loop iterating over all active client sockets) doesn't finish. Will that data be thrown away? Will it be what the next `select` will be triggered with? What happens if I send two messages before the inner loop finishes ? Will I ever face the scenario where inside the loop iterating over all the active sockets I get more than 1 that has "activity" - i.e.: can two `FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)` be true within a single iteration of the loop ?

Comment: Presuming that `select()` is implemented correctly, preferrably with non-blocking sockets, no data will be lost and all data will be received.

Comment: Note to editors: this is strictly speaking neither a C nor a C++ question, it's either a POSIX or a BSD networking question. But the OP meant it as C++, and the site is about "C/C++", so it makes sense to retain the original language tag.

Comment: @user4815162342 note taken. questions wrongly tagging c or c++ are so common that I didn't realize. Should have payed more attention

Comment: @idclev463035818 No worries - the question _is_ technically mistagged, so my comment is more of a plea for lenience towards the OP rather than a criticism of the edit.

Comment: Note that `poll` is generally preferred over `select` in new programs for modern OSes.

Comment: NB. The existing answers are only correct for TCP. The linked code _does_ use `SOCK_STREAM`, so they're correct, but it isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, multiple descriptors can be ready to read in a single iteration. The return value of `select()` is the number of descriptors that are ready, and it can be more than 1. As you loop through the descriptors, you should increment a counter when `FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)` is true, and continue until the counter reaches this number.

But even if you only process one descriptor, nothing will be thrown away. `select()` is not triggered by changes, it returns whenever any of the descriptors is ready to read (or write, if you also use `writefds`). If a descriptor is ready to read, but you don't read from it, it will still be ready to read the next time you call `select()`, so it will return immediately.

However, if you only process the first descriptor you find in the loop, later descriptors could be "starved" if an earlier descriptor is always ready to read, and you never process the later ones. So it's generally best to always process all the ready descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

`select()` is a *level-triggered* API, which means that it answers the question "are any of these file descriptors readable/writable now?", not "have these file descriptors become readable/writable?". That should answer most of your questions:

> But what happens if within a very short time-frame of the first message, I send another one? [...] Will it be what the next `select` will be triggered with?

It will be what the next `select()` will be triggered with.

> What happens if I send two messages before the inner loop finishes ?

That depends on how long the messages are - TCP doesn't work in terms of messages, but in terms of a stream of bytes. The server might well read both messages in a single `read()`. And if it doesn't, the socket will remain readable, and it will pick them up immediately on the next `select()`.

> Will I ever face the scenario where inside the loop iterating over all the active sockets I get more than 1 that has "activity" - i.e.: can two `FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)` be true within a single iteration of the loop ?

Yes, if two clients send data at the same time (while you are out of `select()`), `select()` will report two readable file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already excellent answers:

The `select` function in this case isn't grabbing packets directly from the wire, it's actually going to the packet buffer, usually a part of the [NIC](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/n/nic.htm), to grab packets/frames that are available to be read. The packet buffer is normally a ring buffer: it has a fixed size, new packets come in at the "top", and when the buffer gets full, the oldest packets drop out of the "bottom".

Just as @sam-varshavchik mentioned in the comments, as long as select is implemented correctly and the packet buffer doesn't clog up during the time you are going through the `select` loop, you will be fine.

---

[Here's](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_ethernet_frames_using_an_af_packet_ring_buffer_in_c.html) an interesting article on how to implement a packet ring buffer for a socket.

Comment: note that "above" depends on how the answers are sorted. In my view there are no above answers

Comment: Thanks @idclev463035818 for the note =)